# gcloud preview app deploy throws

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I am not sure what I am doing wrong? I can run the app locally in cloud9. gcloud info doesn't show me anything out of the ordinary... any help

```
xxxxx:~/workspace (master) $ gcloud preview app deploy --version v1
You are about to deploy the following modules:
 - valued-vault-xxxxx/default (from [/home/ubuntu/workspace/app.yaml])
     Deployed URL: [https://valued-vault-xxxxx.appspot.com]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

Beginning deployment...
Copying files to Google Cloud Storage...
Synchronizing files to [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.app.cloud_storage.BucketReference object at 0x7f506914f790>].
File upload done.
Updating module [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Errors were encountered while copying files to App Engine.

Details: [
  [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
      "description": "Conflicting SHA1 sum for file. Expected \"d4fc6996_1e0f9444_1f1f82b3_f1v2eef4_9d5d12345\" but received \"f7f38209_fa22bdf0_9e73e6ec_7f60a936_9efc1f1e\".",
      "resourceName": "https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.valued-vault-xxxxx.appspot.com/f7f3d209fa25bcf09e73efec7f60a9369efc1f1e",
      "resourceType": "file"
    }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. My mistake. Anyway I used to deploy using Codeship to GAE. However even after deleting the project from Codeship it didn't delete the Codeship --> GAE authentication - So I was getting that error. I just realise it now after I deleted the codeship --> GAE connected accounts. Things were working correctly.

In short remove all previous authentication/deploy service before we change deployment env.

Answer (score 9):

Follow following steps:

1. Copy the file part of resource name. Here in your case it will be: f7f3d209fa25bcf09e73efec7f60a9369efc1f1e
2. Go to google cloud storage and select the bucket: staging.valued-vault-xxxxx.appspot.com.appspot.com. "valued-vault-xxxxx.appspot.com" is the project name.
3. Then search for "f7f3d209fa25bcf09e73efec7f60a9369efc1f1e" and delete it
4. Do the deployment again and it should work

Comment: I'm not the originator, but just so you know, this solution worked for a similar issue, I was having. So thank you!

Comment: Any idea why this issue occurs in the first place?